# CMake find_package for Python3 fails upon finding Python 2

Tags: python, cmake

While moving to CMake 3.17.3 (from 3.13.3) we have stumbled on a problem with Python. In the root `CMakeLists.txt` we now have:

```
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter)
```

However, this fails with the following:

```
CMake Error at /home/abadura/cmake/cmake-3.17.3-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_EXECUTABLE Interpreter)

      Reason given by package: 
          Interpreter: Wrong major version for the interpreter "/build/ltesdkroot/Platforms/LINUX/MB_PS_LFS_REL_2020_07_0068/sdk/bld-tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/python"

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/abadura/cmake/cmake-3.17.3-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/abadura/cmake/cmake-3.17.3-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:2437 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /home/abadura/cmake/cmake-3.17.3-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPython3.cmake:309 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)
```

while the Python found (`/build/ltesdkroot/Platforms/LINUX/MB_PS_LFS_REL_2020_07_0068/sdk/bld-tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/python`) reports version `Python 2.7.15+`.

Searching and experimenting I found out that adding:

```
set(Python3_FIND_STRATEGY VERSION)
```

before the `find_package` helps. With this added Python is found:

```
-- Found Python3: /opt/python/x86_64/3.6.0/bin-wrapped/python3.6 (found version "3.6.0") found components: Interpreter
```

Now, the problem is that [FindPython3 documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindPython3.html) states the following:

> `Python3_FIND_STRATEGY`
>
> This variable defines how lookup will be done. The
> `Python3_FIND_STRATEGY` variable can be set to one of the following:
>
> - `VERSION`: Try to find the most recent version in all specified locations. This is the default if policy [CMP0094](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/policy/CMP0094.html#policy:CMP0094) is undefined or
>   set to `OLD`.
> - `LOCATION`: Stops lookup as soon as a version satisfying version constraints is founded. This is the default if policy [CMP0094](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/policy/CMP0094.html#policy:CMP0094) is
>   set to `NEW`.

So, the `LOCATION` should work OK based on my understanding of the description. It should ignore the `/build/ltesdkroot/Platforms/LINUX/MB_PS_LFS_REL_2020_07_0068/sdk/bld-tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/python` since it doesn't satisfy version constraints (it is Python 2 rather than Python 3) and should continue to find the `/opt/python/x86_64/3.6.0/bin-wrapped/python3.6` which does satisfy the constraints. (For completeness, I tried adding explicit `3.6` version in `find_package` and it didn't change anything.)

Another issue is whether I should set `Python3_FIND_STRATEGY` or use [CMP0094](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/policy/CMP0094.html#policy:CMP0094) directly. The [CMP0094](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/policy/CMP0094.html#policy:CMP0094) documentation has a somewhat scary warning:

> Note The `OLD` behavior of a policy is [deprecated by definition](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake-policies.7.html#manual:cmake-policies(7))
> and may be removed in a future version of CMake.

So, I'm not sure which approach (setting `Python3_FIND_STRATEGY` or activating `OLD` for [CMP0094](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/policy/CMP0094.html#policy:CMP0094)) is the desired (stable) approach.